# Is it possible to use Deno without typescript?

Tags: typescript, deno

I want to disable typescript when using Deno.

I know I can pass `--config .deno` but how do I tell the compiler to just support vanilla js and no typescript?

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "checkJs": true
  }
}
```

I'm aware of --no-check but wondering if I can set this in a config file.

Comment: It's a very interesting question!!! By ***disable typescript*** , what behavior are we expecting from ***deno runtime***? Certainly, I am beginner too, but even I am curious for this one?  At least from the documentation it is clear that it can ***`execute`*** `javascript` or `typescript`(either or both), but disabling isn't something covered anywhere...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to opt out of compiler transpilation of TypeScript source code when using Deno.

V8 (the JS engine used by Deno) does not execute TypeScript, so all TS must be transpiled to JavaScript in order to be run.

If you don't want to use TypeScript, then write JavaScript source files and use the `--no-check` CLI option to ensure that all dependencies (including transitive) emit no compiler diagnostics.

Comment: so no way to configure noCheck int he file??

Comment: No, configuration of runtime arguments is not supported by the [config](https://deno.land/manual/getting_started/configuration_file). (That could lead to privilege escalation by programs with write permission.) If you want this behavior to be persistent, you can create a wrapper function for deno in your shell or use a shell script.